# Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, maven, selenium, continuous-integration

i am trying to run selenium tests as part of maven build, and this is my reference:
http://www.gitshah.com/2010/10/how-to-run-selenium-tests-as-part-of.html?showComment=1326627249570#c2296284119877744512

1. **Dependencies**:

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.2</version> 
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdriver-firefox</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.7376</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. **Plugins**:

   ```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
       </plugin>

       <!-- Selenium plugin to start selenium server -->

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                   <execution>
                   <id>start</id>
                   <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>start-server</goal>
                       </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <background>true</background>
                       <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>

               <execution>
               <id>stop</id>
               <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>stop-server</goal>
                       </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
   </plugin>

       <!-- Cargo plugin to start servlet container when integration test runs -->

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
           <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <wait>false</wait> 
               <container>
               <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                   <type>installed</type>
                   <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
               </container>
           </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                   <id>start-container</id>
                   <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>start</goal>
                           <goal>deploy</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                   <id>stop-container</id>
                   <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>stop</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
       </plugin> 

       <plugin>

               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.8</version>

               <configuration>
                   <junitArtifactName>
                   org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit
                   </junitArtifactName>
                   <excludes>

                       <exclude>**/unit/*Test.java</exclude>
                   </excludes>
               </configuration>


               <executions>
                   <execution>

                   <id>integration-tests</id>
                   <phase>integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>test</goal>
                       </goals>
                   <configuration>
                   <skip>false</skip>
                   <excludes>
                       <exclude>none</exclude>
                   </excludes>

                   <includes>
                      <include>**/integration/*Test.java</include>
                   </includes>
                   </configuration>
                   </execution>
           </executions>

           </plugin>
   ```

when running the integration test (the firefox opens a blank page), and i am getting the following exception:

```
 Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055
```

**UPDATE**: i am using firefox 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error is gone after using the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.16.1</version>         
        </dependency>
```

and removing this one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdriver-firefox</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.7376</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need at least Selenium version 2.15 to support Firefox 9 (ref. http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG).

Comment: I also got the following error during using FF 12 with WebDriver:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null

I stopped the autoupdate of FF, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The bug is fixed in v36.01 if you have that version and problem still occurs reinstal it again